# Enabling Service Broker on a database involved in an availability group

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, service-broker, availability-groups

I'm trying to enable Service Broker on a SQL Server 2012 database that is part of an availability group and keep getting this error message:

> The operation cannot be performed on database "dbname" because it is involved in a database mirroring session or an availability group. Some operations are not allowed on a database that is participating in a database mirroring session or in an availability group.
>   ALTER DATABASE statement failed. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 1468)

Even attempting to enable `Trustworthy` on the database generates the same error.  According to [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh710058.aspx), it seems that Service Broker could be enabled on databases configured for AG.  What could I be missing?

The listener has been configured, endpoints created with public permission, targets reference the listener name.  The error occurs when I try to enable service broker or set `Trustworthy` via management console or T-SQL.

I wanted to add that the database is a restore from a SQL Server 2005 version with a existing Service Broker implementation.

Answer (score 8):

> I wanted to add that the database is a restore from a SQL Server 2005

When you restore a database the Service Broker in it gets disabled and must be explicitly enabled (there are reasons why this is necessary, but I won't go into them). If you restored the DB and then set up the AG w/o enabling broker first, you have set up the AG w/o the Service Broker enabled and now you cannot run the `ALTER DATABASE SET ENABLE_BROKER`.  Unfortunately to set it up correctly you must enable broker *before* adding it to the AG, which means you must tear apart the AG, enable broker, then set set up the AG again.